# Laravel 5 : How to use simple birth date middleware(before filter)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to print "Happy Birthday" if date is match else I want to show something. So I use middleware in my "/" route.

My route

```
Route::get('/', ['middleware' => 'dob', function(){
    return 'Hello World';
}]);
```

My kernel

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
        'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
        'dob' => 'App\Http\Middleware\DateOfBirth'
    ];
```

My Middleware/DateOfBirth.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->date('d/m') == '15/09' ){
            echo 'happy birthday';
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

I just change current date to 15 and access public app but why it's show `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::date()` instead of "Happy Birthday" ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `print_r($request)` if the date has been passed to the routes.

Comment: @aldrin27 Where  i should put `print_r($request)` ? maybe you can help to answer. Thanks.

Comment: Above your if statement then `exit;`

Comment: What are you expecting `$request->date()` to output? Are you trying to retrieve an input called date, or are you just trying to get the current date? If so, you don't need the request object to retrieve that, you can use `date('d/m')` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just a little bit different with filter in Laravel 4

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(date('d/m') == '15/09' ){
        echo 'happy birthday';
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says the problem is your call to the date() method on the request object. The default Request Class doesn't implement this method - did you extend the request class with this method? Or do you want to access any input data or data from A model or simply mean the php date() function?
If you tell US what this method call should do then we can help better!?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, there is not `date()` method on the request object. I think you need something more like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $date = $request->get('date');

    if((new \DateTime($date))->format('d/m') == '15/09' ){
        echo 'happy birthday';
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```